# css triangle 'out of line' relative to other elements

Tags: css

I've created a control bar in js for my audio elements, and am trying to style the play button (class `playPause`) using a css triangle. My problem is that the triangle is raised several pixels relative to the rest of the control elements. As if it had `margin-` or `padding-bottom`, but the console shows no such thing, and explicitly styling those properties to 0 has no effect.

The controls are added as such:

```
$( this ).after(  
    '<div class="audio_controls_bar">\
        <span id="' + playPauseId + '" class="playPause" ></span>\
        <input id="' + seekSliderId + '" class="seekSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">\
        <span id="' + timeTxtId + '"></span>\
        <span id="' + muteBtnId + '" class="mute" ></span>\
        <input id="' + volumeSliderId + '" class="volumeSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1">\
    </div>'
);
```

the span indicating text is styled `inline-block`, and also has these styles added:

```
playBtn.style.width = "0"; 
playBtn.style.height = "0"; 
playBtn.style.borderTop = "10px solid transparent";
playBtn.style.borderBottom = "10px solid transparent";
playBtn.style.borderLeft = "10px solid white";
```

When these styles are not applied, no such 'bumping' occurs.

... worth mentioning, if text is added to the playPause span, that text appears at the same relative height to the other elements.

... also worth mentioning: a div creates the same effect, however, a `button` element has the same (and opposite) problem, of mysterious un-findable padding on top.

Any idea what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's quite common for a CSS triangle to hang lower or higher depending on other elements.

As example: I made an arrow and placed it inbetween text on http://jsfiddle.net/xdqFk/
I fixed the position by adding 2px to the bottom margin: `margin: 0 6px 2px 6px;` (top right bottom left) pushing it up.

In your case, where it's higher, a negative margin like this should work:

```
playBtn.style.width = "0"; 
playBtn.style.height = "0"; 
playBtn.style.borderTop = "10px solid transparent";
playBtn.style.borderRight = "10px solid transparent";
playBtn.style.borderBottom = "10px solid transparent";
playBtn.style.borderLeft = "10px solid white";
playBtn.style.marginBottom = "-5px"; // CHANGE THIS
```

Comment: ok, thanks. that works. any idea why this happens? or why it would be different for the `button` element? normally you can see what sorts of styles are being applied by the browser, etc.

Comment: @GregoryTippett Not entirely, but I understand it since you actually have nothing, just look at it: `width: 0; height: 0;`, from that point on it's all about the chosen size of the borders as well as other elements and styles as to where one could expect it to hang around.

Comment: ok. according to this rather old article: http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/styling-form-buttons/  , button styling often has more to do with the operating system than the browser... hmmm. so is there a danger that while I get this to look fine on my pc, it will break on a mac?

Comment: @GregoryTippett Buttons can look different everywhere indeed, but the arrow is usually cross-browser, at least mine look exactly how I want on all browsers